# Timeshift schedules not working on Fedora and Manjaro. Why? Systemd?

Tags: backup, fedora, cron, manjaro, scheduling

Nowadays I am using Fedora and Manajro mostly. I use openSUSE and sometimes min Mint.
I have installed TimeShift in my machine with Manjaro and a friend's machine with Fedora. In both the scheduled tasks are not working. 
I see nothing in crontab (/var/spool/cron/) there are two file in /etc/cron.d/ : timeshift-boot and timeshift-hourly. For testing I enabled all schedules and no new files were created in cron's directories: cron.hourly, cron.daily, cron.weekly, cron.monthly nor cron.d in /etc.
Both machines with the same result.
I also use Duplicity and there is no problem with it. (different tool and backup method but...).
What is happening? Does it have anything to do with Systemd Times(timers whatever it is called)?